# Disable caching / pooling of EntityManager in WebSphere Liberty

Tags: hibernate, jpa, websphere-liberty

We currently migrating our JEE application to WebSphere Liberty. It's already running fine in  WebSphere 8.5 Full Profile and some other application servers. We are using the multitenancy feature in Hibernate. The Tenant is resolved using the `resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier()` method. This is called when the `EntityManager` is created. We use a Container-Managed `EntityManager` in a Stateless Bean. But in WebSphere, the stateless bean is returned from a pool. If the user switches the tenant the container returns the same stateless bean with the same `EntityManager` (--> with the old tenant). In WebSphere full profile the `EntityManger` is recreated by the container, but not in Liberty. Does anyone have an idea of how to avoid the caching / pooling of the `EntityManager`?

I already tried to recreate the `EntityManager` myself but if I do so, I get back an application-managed `EntityManger` (not container-managed), but that's not what I want.
I also tried the jpa setting `entityManagerPoolCapacity` in Liberty's `server.xml` which sounds promising but does not have any effect:

```
<jpa entityManagerPoolCapacity="1" />
```

How we create the EntityManager:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "PU")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

How I tried to manually recreate the EntityManager:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

JPA: 2.0

Hibernate: 4.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While playing around with the configuration, `EntityManagerPoolCapacity` turned out to be the right setting for that. But you need to set it to 0 to disable the caching/pooling correctly:

```
<jpa entityManagerPoolCapacity="0" />
```